# How to create a gwt composite component with children using uibinder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I would like to create a component to decorate its children, such as:

mycomponent.ui.xml:

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="myStyle">
    <!-- how can i render children ? -->
</g:FlowPanel>
```

and then others can use:

```
<myapp:mycomponent>
    <g:Label>Decorated child</g:Label>
</myapp:mycomponent>
```

How can i render the children in uibinder? (or in Java, if i must)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let `MyComponent` implement the `HasWidgets` interface for adding/removing child widgets.

The `MyComponent.ui.xml` looks as simple as

```
<g:FlowPanel ui:field="main" />
```

while you delegate the methods specified ind `HasWidgets` to the `FlowPanel`:

```
public class MyComponent extends Composite implements HasWidgets {

    private static MyComponentUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyComponentUiBinder.class);

    interface MyComponentUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyComponent> {}

    @UiField
    FlowPanel main;

    public MyComponent() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w) {
        main.add(w);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        main.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Widget> iterator() {
        return main.iterator();
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Widget w) {
        return main.remove(w);
    }
}
```

Calling

```
<M:MyComponent>
    <g:Label text="some text" />
</M:MyComponent>
```

will work this way.

Comment: Is there any performance hit for not Injecting the MyComponentUiBinder, instead of GWT.create-ing it?

Comment: AFAIK injecting is using GWT.create so I'd say no

Answer (score 1):

Using this XML:

```
<myapp:mycomponent>
    <g:Label>Decorated child</g:Label> 
</myapp:mycomponent>
```

will instantiate `MyComponent` and then call `MyComponent.add(label)`. All you have to do is override `.add(..)` in your class `MyComponent` and apply any styles that you want to passed components.