# Custom widgets containing other HTML/widgets

Tags: gwt, widget

I'm trying to create a custom widget that would internally be 
represented by a simple `DIV` and a `BUTTON` element, but which would accept 
other widgets inside it, pretty much like `HTMLPanel`.

So, I want something like this...

```
<div class="XXX">
  <button class="YYY"></button>
  {other widget(s) here}
</div>
```

...encapsulated inside some widget, say `WrapperWidget`. Then, I could use 
this `WrapperWidget` inside some other (multiple) ui.xml files:

```
<ns:WrapperWidget>
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
   </ul>
</ns:WrapperWidget>
```

How is that achievable in GWT?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a gwt composite component with children using uibinder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175216/how-to-create-a-gwt-composite-component-with-children-using-uibinder)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use UI binder, so I can't help you there.
To nest widgets, one would usually use a Composite http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html

Comment: Thanks. I've got something working by extending `ComplexPanel`. However this won't accept HTML elements as children. Only other `Widget`s.

Comment: So you have to extend HtmlPanel, as this are the only panels that except html as childs.