# Create custom widget and allow nested sub-elements in UiBinder

Tags: gwt

I want to create a custom widget that allows to specify its nested sub-elements in UiBinder. Just like `DockPanel` can have `south`, `north`, etc. I looked at the source code of `DockPanel` but haven't found a solution.

```
<my:LeftRightToolbar>
    <left>
        <g:Button/>
    </left>

    <right>
        <g:Button/>
    </right>        
</my:LeftRightToolbar>
```

**UPDATE:** Can I have multiple sub nodes under my custom `<left>` and `<right>`? The code doesn't compile if I add more than one widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing - `<left>` and `<right>` have to be in the same namespace as `LeftRightToolbar`, so it should be `<my:left>` and `<my:right>`.

Secondly, you need to annotate two methods in `LeftRightToolbar` with the [`@UiChild`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html) annotation:

```java
@UiChild(tagname = "left")
void addToLeft(Widget widget) {
    left.add(widget);
}

@UiChild(tagname = "right")
void addToRight(Widget widget) {
    right.add(widget);
}
```

The method `addToLeft` will be called to add the widget specified in `<my:left>` tags. The `<my:right>` tag is handled by `addToRight`.

If you need to add multiple widgets to your custom tags, you should put a container in them, like `FlowPanel`.

Comment: Thanks! And if I don't want to have `my:left` and `my:right` childs and add widgets directly under `<my:LeftRightToolbar>`. Is it possible?

Comment: And the second question: if I have a method `@UiChild(tagname="data")
    public void addData(String key, String value) {`. Can I pass key and value from UiBinder somehow?

Comment: You can't add keys and attributes to your custom tags. But you could add the needed tags on the `LeftRightToolbar` element though. You can pass arguments to your widget's constructors (using @UiConstructor or [other methods](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Using_a_widget)).

Comment: Thanks! And what about my first question?

Comment: In my case it looks ugly: `<my2:Menu>
                    <my2:item>
                        <my2:MenuItem text="1 Monat" key="period" value="P1M" />
                    </my2:item>`

Comment: You can put widgets directly in your `LeftRightToolbar` - it has to implement the `HasWidgets` interface. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4175216/181497.

Comment: It's generally discouraged to extend your original question with further questions - in the future you should just create a new question. Answer updated.